# what does Sql Server Management want to save into "Solution1"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

what is "solution1"?
what is it for?
When I exit ssms, it asks me to save something under Solution1
David

Comment: Easily the most annoying feature of SSMS 2008... and no way to turn it off :(

Answer (score 1):

Because it assumes you're a fan of Visual Studio and like to think of every project, every collection of SQL scripts, as a "solution".

Comment: it **IS** Visual Studio - with a different "skin"

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174161.aspx)

SSMS just allows you to save your sql files in projects/solutions just like in (e.g.) Visual Studion. This allows you to group related files together e.g. you could create a solution for your database, and save all the table/sproc/function scripts etc in it. "Solution1" is just the default name